# phpmailer Exception while using Pixel & Tonic contact-form plugin

Tags: plugin-contactform

Link to Github repository for plugin: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm

Being given an error by the plugin where it is interpreting my Twig variable literally as a string instead of what the variable is representing. I am looking for a way to fix this using the current set-up but having an alternate setup is fine as well. Also for reference, I have followed the guidelines on the README in regards to changing the craft/config/contactform.php file. Much appreciated for the help!

This is my code:

```
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
{% if errors %}
    <ul class="errors">
        {% for error in errors %}
            <li><span>{{ error }}</span></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import errorList %}

<div class="uk-width-large-1-2 uk-width-medium-1-2 uk-width-small-1-1 uk-container-center">
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm/sendMessage">

    <ul id="button-content" class="uk-switcher uk-margin">
        <li class="text-space basic-border">
            <h3><b>Email to {{default.defaultcontactreason}}</b></h3>
            <input type="hidden" name="toEmail" value="{{ '{{default.defaultContactEmail}}'|hash }}">{{default.defaultContactEmail}}
        </li>
    {% for category in craft.entries.section('Contacts') %}
        <li class="text-space basic-border">
            <h3><b>Email to {{ category.contactReason }}</b></h3>
            <input type="hidden" name="toEmail" value="{{ '{{category.contactEmail}}'|hash }}">{{category.contactEmail}}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <h3><label for="fromName">Your Name</label></h3>
    <input id="fromName" type="text" name="fromName" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromName }}{% endif %}">
    {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromName')) }}

    <h3><label for="fromEmail">Your Email</label></h3>
    <input id="fromEmail" type="text" name="fromEmail" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromEmail }}{% endif %}">
    {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}

    <h3><label for="subject">Subject</label></h3>
    <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.subject }}{% endif %}">
    {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('subject')) }}

    <h3><label for="message">Message</label></h3>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="message" name="message">{% if message is defined %}{{ message.message }}{% endif %}</textarea>
    {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('message')) }}

    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{siteUrl}}Contacts">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: for reference, the exact exception reads: Invalid address: {{category.contactEmail}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got some nested escape tags in Twig, which is a no-no.

```
value="{{ '{{category.contactEmail}}'|hash }}"
```

You just need to use:

```
value="{{ category.contactEmail|hash }}"
```